# PHP Array - grouping by pairs of two

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array looking like this:

```
["my_arr"]=>
{
  [0]=> "111"
  [1]=> "aaa"
  [2]=> "222"
  [3]=> "bbb"
}
```

My aim is to format to look like this:

```
["my_arr"]=>
{
  [0]=>
    [0]=> "111"
    [1]=> "aaa"
  [1]=>
    [0]=> "222"
    [1]=> "bbb"
}
```

How can I do it?

My idea is to use a foreach loop with a counter (or maybe even modulo) and put the values into a new array every two "steps", but I think this solution does seem to be very solid. Is there any better way?

Comment: this should be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822305/combine-pairs-to-groups-php-arrays

Answer (score 5):

Check out [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
<?php
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
?>
```

Will give you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
```